# Make Search using firebase in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-native

I am new to react native and firebase. I want to make a search bar that can search all data from firebase according to Barcode value, but I'm facing some errors while doing it. I think that my code is wrong somewhere but don't know where. I have transferred the firebase credentials to **dbConfig.js** . Here is my firebase data [firebase data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPiBZ.jpg) and my **code**:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text,TextInput,StyleSheet,Image, Button} from 'react-native';

import firebase from './dbConfig';

export default class ListItem extends Component {

render() {
        return (
<>

<View style={styles.BackGround}>
      <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
    <Image
        source={require('./mic.png')} //mic image here
        style={styles.ImageStyle}
    />


    <TextInput
        style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 12}}
        placeholder="Search for Product"
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        //onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({data: text})}
        onSubmitEditing = {(text)=> this.setState({data: text})}
        value = {this.state.data}
       // onSubmitEditing={()=>this._search}
        //onSubmitEditing={()=>this.componentWillMount}
    />
    <Image
        source={require('./usr.png')} //icon image here
        style={styles.ImageStyle2}
    />
</View>


             <View>
             <Text>{this.state.items}</Text> 
            </View>
</View>
            </>
        );
    }


    constructor(props){
      super(props);

     this.state= {
          items: '',
          data: '',

       };
      }
    componentWillMount(){


      var ref = firebase.database().ref('/');

      ref.child(this.state.data).on("value", snapshot =>{

      console.log(snapshot.val().info.Price);
//if(snapshot.val().Price == this.state.data){
//this.setState({items: Object.values(snapshot.val())});
//}
//else{
 //alert('there is problem');
//}
      });
    }

}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({



  BackGround: {
    backgroundColor: '#22abb6',
    height: '100%'



   },

   SectionStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    // borderWidth: 0.8,
    // borderColor: '#000',
    shadowColor:'#176f75',

    marginTop: 50,
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 10,
    margin: 10,
  },


  ImageStyle: {
    padding: 10,
    marginLeft: 10,
    margin: 5,
    height: 25,
    width: 25,
    resizeMode: 'stretch',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  ImageStyle2: {
    padding: 10,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    margin: 5,
    height: 25,
    width: 25,
    resizeMode: 'stretch',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },


});
```

Comment: I have imported firebase credentials using dbConfig.js file

Comment: I'm getting the data easily but not able to push the keyword/barcode to firebase for my requirement. For example, 10001 is barcode of Washing machine, I am getting "Washing Machine" as output when i manually search(assigning data = 10001) for it. but not working in my  search.

Comment: have you tried remove the first slash before de "14": Like =>  ```var ref = firebase.database().ref('14/info');```

Comment: its working when i assign manually[ data= 10001]; it gives output as "Washing Machine". but not working as search

Comment: i tried removing slash before "14", but its still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by changing the follows:

```
 //adding this in TextInput

onSubmitEditing = {this.componentWillMount}



//on changing the function compoundWillMount to async()

 componentWillMount= async()=>{
```